# Adding Custom Fields to Sales Order header

Tags: acumatica, custom-fields

I have added some custom fields to the Customer Location window for License Info i.e. License Number and Expiration Date.

I now want these fields to appear on the Sales Order Header and change if the Customer Location changes.

I thought this would be easy, but the custom fields do not appear to auto link on this screen.

Answer (score 0):

To add this to the sales order header, I would first need to declare a current customer location view in your Graph Extension:

```
public PXSelectReadonly<Location, Where<Location.locationID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerLocationID>>>> CurrentCustomerLocation;
```

And then you can add a new FormView, set the DataMember to CurrentCustomerLocation, and then reference the fields. This would be similar to what is found on the Customers screen (AR303000) on the General Info tab => DefContact.